# Rails: Conditional nested attributes in edit form

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, nested-attributes

I have a model called `Offer` and another called `PurchasinGroup`

`Offer` has many `PurchasingGroups`

`Offer` accepts nested attributes for `PurchasingGroups`

While creating an offer you can add as many PurchasingGroups as you want.

`PurchasingGroup` has a boolean attribute called `active`.

while editing an `Offer` you can see all the created PurchasingGroups, however I want to let the user edit only the PurchasingGroups that are active, and do not display the inactive purchasing groups.

This is my `edit` action in `offers_controller.rb`:

```
def edit
  @offer = Offer.find(params[:id])
end
```

And this is my form (only the part that matters):

```
<fieldset>
        <legend>Purchasing groups</legend>
        <%= f.fields_for :purchasing_groups do |builder| %>
            <%= render partial: 'purchasing_group_fields', locals: { f: builder } %>
        <% end %>
    </fieldset>
```

In the edit form all the purchasing groups are being shown for edit, I want to show only those that are active I mean `purchasing_group.active == true`

How is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<%= f.fields_for :purchasing_groups, @offer.purchasing_groups.where(active: true) do |builder| %>
    <%= render partial: 'purchasing_group_fields', locals: { f: builder } %>
<% end %>
```

on the other hand, you can also add a association in your model

```
class Offer
    has_many :active_purchasing_groups, class_name: "PurchasinGroup", -> { where(active:true) }
    ...
end
```

and then

```
<%= f.fields_for :active_purchasing_groups do |builder| %>
    <%= render partial: 'purchasing_group_fields', locals: { f: builder } %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Wonderful!, I did not know that you can pass queries to `f.fields_for`, thank you so much you saved my day. Regards!

Comment: Hi after add what you told me it works ok, however when there is an error in the form the purchasing group is reset, I mean it does not show the last entered values... that is an usability issue...